# srand() inside thread causing stack overflow when memory was very low

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-c++, memory, stack-overflow

This is multithreaded application being developed in C/C++ in VisualStudio on Windows XP.

User reported that it crashed with error "Stack Overflow"

After debugging, it is found that call `srand()` in one of threads causing "Stack Overflow" when computer was running very low on memory. Surprisingly, there was nothing causing big stack (static array etc.) in the thread function that calls `srand()`

This is how stack after crash looked like:

```
 MyApplication.exe!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum=16)  Line 217    C
 MyApplication.exe!_amsg_exit(int rterrnum=16)  Line 441 + 0x9 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_getptd()  Line 525 + 0x7 bytes    C

 MyApplication.exe!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 243 + 0x5 bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_woutput_s_l(_iobuf * stream=0x57674054, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * argptr=0x5767c1ec)  Line 1023    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_vswprintf_helper(int (_iobuf *, const wchar_t *, localeinfo_struct *, char *)* woutfn=0x0047d580, unsigned short * string=0x57675158, unsigned int count=4076, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x5767c1ec)  Line 157 + 0x13 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s_l(unsigned short * string=0x57675158, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x5767c1ec)  Line 324 + 0x21 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s(unsigned short * string=0x57675158, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, char * ap=0x5767c1ec)  Line 376 + 0x1b bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x5767c1ec)  Line 515 + 0x36 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x5767c1ec)  Line 241 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, ...)  Line 258 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum=16)  Line 215 + 0x11 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_amsg_exit(int rterrnum=16)  Line 441 + 0x9 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_getptd()  Line 525 + 0x7 bytes    C

 MyApplication.exe!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 243 + 0x5 bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_woutput_s_l(_iobuf * stream=0x5767c974, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * argptr=0x57684b0c)  Line 1023    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_vswprintf_helper(int (_iobuf *, const wchar_t *, localeinfo_struct *, char *)* woutfn=0x0047d580, unsigned short * string=0x5767da78, unsigned int count=4076, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x57684b0c)  Line 157 + 0x13 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s_l(unsigned short * string=0x5767da78, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x57684b0c)  Line 324 + 0x21 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s(unsigned short * string=0x5767da78, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, char * ap=0x57684b0c)  Line 376 + 0x1b bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x57684b0c)  Line 515 + 0x36 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x57684b0c)  Line 241 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, ...)  Line 258 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum=16)  Line 215 + 0x11 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_amsg_exit(int rterrnum=16)  Line 441 + 0x9 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_getptd()  Line 525 + 0x7 bytes    C

 MyApplication.exe!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 243 + 0x5 bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_woutput_s_l(_iobuf * stream=0x57685294, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * argptr=0x5768d42c)  Line 1023    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_vswprintf_helper(int (_iobuf *, const wchar_t *, localeinfo_struct *, char *)* woutfn=0x0047d580, unsigned short * string=0x57686398, unsigned int count=4076, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x5768d42c)  Line 157 + 0x13 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s_l(unsigned short * string=0x57686398, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x5768d42c)  Line 324 + 0x21 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s(unsigned short * string=0x57686398, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, char * ap=0x5768d42c)  Line 376 + 0x1b bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x5768d42c)  Line 515 + 0x36 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x5768d42c)  Line 241 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, ...)  Line 258 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum=16)  Line 215 + 0x11 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_amsg_exit(int rterrnum=16)  Line 441 + 0x9 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_getptd()  Line 525 + 0x7 bytes    C

 MyApplication.exe!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 243 + 0x5 bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_woutput_s_l(_iobuf * stream=0x5768dbb4, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * argptr=0x57695d4c)  Line 1023    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_vswprintf_helper(int (_iobuf *, const wchar_t *, localeinfo_struct *, char *)* woutfn=0x0047d580, unsigned short * string=0x5768ecb8, unsigned int count=4076, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x57695d4c)  Line 157 + 0x13 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s_l(unsigned short * string=0x5768ecb8, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x57695d4c)  Line 324 + 0x21 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s(unsigned short * string=0x5768ecb8, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, char * ap=0x57695d4c)  Line 376 + 0x1b bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x57695d4c)  Line 515 + 0x36 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x57695d4c)  Line 241 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, ...)  Line 258 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum=16)  Line 215 + 0x11 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_amsg_exit(int rterrnum=16)  Line 441 + 0x9 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_getptd()  Line 525 + 0x7 bytes    C

 MyApplication.exe!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 243 + 0x5 bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_woutput_s_l(_iobuf * stream=0x576964d4, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * argptr=0x5769e66c)  Line 1023    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_vswprintf_helper(int (_iobuf *, const wchar_t *, localeinfo_struct *, char *)* woutfn=0x0047d580, unsigned short * string=0x576975d8, unsigned int count=4076, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x5769e66c)  Line 157 + 0x13 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s_l(unsigned short * string=0x576975d8, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x5769e66c)  Line 324 + 0x21 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s(unsigned short * string=0x576975d8, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, char * ap=0x5769e66c)  Line 376 + 0x1b bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x5769e66c)  Line 515 + 0x36 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x5769e66c)  Line 241 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, ...)  Line 258 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum=16)  Line 215 + 0x11 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_amsg_exit(int rterrnum=16)  Line 441 + 0x9 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_getptd()  Line 525 + 0x7 bytes    C

 MyApplication.exe!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 243 + 0x5 bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_woutput_s_l(_iobuf * stream=0x5769edf4, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * argptr=0x576a6f8c)  Line 1023    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_vswprintf_helper(int (_iobuf *, const wchar_t *, localeinfo_struct *, char *)* woutfn=0x0047d580, unsigned short * string=0x5769fef8, unsigned int count=4076, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x576a6f8c)  Line 157 + 0x13 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s_l(unsigned short * string=0x5769fef8, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x576a6f8c)  Line 324 + 0x21 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s(unsigned short * string=0x5769fef8, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, char * ap=0x576a6f8c)  Line 376 + 0x1b bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x576a6f8c)  Line 515 + 0x36 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x576a6f8c)  Line 241 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, ...)  Line 258 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum=16)  Line 215 + 0x11 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_amsg_exit(int rterrnum=16)  Line 441 + 0x9 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_getptd()  Line 525 + 0x7 bytes    C

 MyApplication.exe!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate(localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 243 + 0x5 bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_woutput_s_l(_iobuf * stream=0x576a7714, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * argptr=0x576af8ac)  Line 1023    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_vswprintf_helper(int (_iobuf *, const wchar_t *, localeinfo_struct *, char *)* woutfn=0x0047d580, unsigned short * string=0x576a8818, unsigned int count=4076, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x576af8ac)  Line 157 + 0x13 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s_l(unsigned short * string=0x576a8818, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000, char * ap=0x576af8ac)  Line 324 + 0x21 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_vsnwprintf_s(unsigned short * string=0x576a8818, unsigned int sizeInWords=4096, unsigned int count=4075, const wchar_t * format=0x0049aca0, char * ap=0x576af8ac)  Line 376 + 0x1b bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x576af8ac)  Line 515 + 0x36 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, char * arglist=0x576af8ac)  Line 241 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType=1, const wchar_t * szFile=0x00000000, int nLine=0, const wchar_t * szModule=0x00000000, const wchar_t * szFormat=0x0049aca0, ...)  Line 258 + 0x1d bytes    C++
 MyApplication.exe!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum=16)  Line 215 + 0x11 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_amsg_exit(int rterrnum=16)  Line 441 + 0x9 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!_getptd()  Line 525 + 0x7 bytes    C
 MyApplication.exe!srand(unsigned int seed=231)  Line 37 + 0x5 bytes    C
>MyApplication.exe!ThreadFunction()  Line 126 + 0xa bytes   C++
```

So we can clearly see a block of calls goes in recurssion finally causing "Stack Overflow"

I was wondering if low memory can really cause stack overflow. So I written trial code that allocates memory till it gets full and then calls a function which has big stack allocation.

**However, the program did not fail.** Below is the code:

```
void CallFunctionWithBigStack()
{
    char stack[10240];
    stack[10231] = 123; // Let's use 'stack' array so that optimizer won't discard it while compiling
    srand(stack[10231]);
}

void AllocateMem (int ChunkSize)
{
    unsigned char* ptr;
    unsigned int i=0;
    while(1)
    {
        ptr = (unsigned char*) malloc (ChunkSize);

        if (ptr)
            printf ("\nAllocating %d bytes", ChunkSize);
        else
        {
            printf ("\nERROR allocating memory");
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Allocate memory till it gets full
    AllocateMem (1024*1024*10); // Allocate in 10 of Megabytes
    AllocateMem (1024*1024); // Allocate in Megabytes
    AllocateMem (1024); // Allocate in Kilobytes

    // Now that memory is full, try calling function that has 10K stack
    CallFunctionWithBigStack();
    return 0;
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Can low memory at all cause "Stack Overflow" especially when there is nothing much on stack and no recursions.
2. What else could have caused srand() to go in iterations of functions causing stack overflow.
3. If "stack overflow" cannnot be caught by exception handlers, how this can be handled if it is going to happen when memory is low.

Answer (score 0):

1. In this case `srand` is calling another function that fails due to low memory and doesn't recover well from that. Hence the recursion and stack overflow.
2. See answer 1. This looks like a bug in the C runtime library.

What sort of exception handling did you try?

Comment: I tried `try/catch(...)` but it didn't catch stack overflow. But I just now got hint. the documentation states:

`The function srand() is not reentrant or thread-safe` May be that was the reason?

Comment: Since this is C you should use __try. See in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zazxh1a9.aspx)

Comment: Yes, this is a bug.  You are welcome to report the bug via [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).  The process is about to die anyway--this failure to allocate per-thread storage to store the rand state is fatal--so while dying via stack overflow may be trickier to debug, the outcome of process termination is not worse than what would happen otherwise.